# Publish in Matlab truncates part of my text

Tags: matlab

I am using publish in Matlab to create html and pdfs. however, part of my text gets truncated. Wondering what's work around on that?

Thanks.

report.m is...

```
disp([runDate]);
disp([categorical(COMPANY)]);
disp([TICKER, CUSIP]);
disp(categorical([SECTOR, SUBIND]));
```

Then to publish...

```
publishList = {'report.m'};
publish(publishList{1}, options);
```

Output looks like... but "Production" is cut off at the end...
[image]

Comment: Your problem is reproducible but you should provide [an executable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Have you tried using fprintf function, instead of disp ?